# Knowing which file-descriptors are ready after select() call in C

Tags: c, sockets, select-function

I'm new to socket programming and I've been introduced to the `select()` system call. My question is, lets say I'm writing a server in C (which I am attempting to do) and I want to use the `select()` call in my implementation for practice. I'm trying to write a server that receives information from a client, so my approach is to use `select()`, followed by `read()` and just output the information.

According to the documentation I've read `select()` returns the *number* of file descriptors in the input set which are ready for i/o. My question is, how do know *which* file descriptors in the original set are the ones that are ready for i/o? I can't seem to find this in my searches or examples I've looked at for the past while.

Let's say my code looks like the below:

```
int main() {
/* Create socket/server variables */
    int select_value;
    int this_socket;
    int maxfd;
    struct sockadder_in address; 
    fd_set allset;

    /* Bind the socket to a port */
    main_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (main_socket < 0) {
        perror("socket()");
        exit(1);
    }

    Connect(main_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address));

    /* Add the socket to the list of fds to be monitored */
    FD_ZERO(&allset);
    FD_SET(main_socket, &allset);

    fd_set read_ready = allset;
    fd_set write_ready = allset;

    while (1) {
        /* Listen for a connection */
        /* Accept a connection */
        select_value = Select(maxfd+1, &read_ready, &write_ready, NULL, NULL);
        if (select_value == -1) {
            perror("select()");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if(select_value > 0) {
            /* How to access i/o ready file descriptors
            now that we know there are some available? */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) instead of the older `select`. Google for "C10K problem"

Comment: I definitely will look into it for a future practice project, thanks for suggesting it!

Comment: RTFM, in particular the manpages for `select` and `select_tut`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can do this using the `FD_ISSET` macro that is part of `<sys/select.h>`.

When your `select` unblocks and a file descriptor is ready, you can test all of your file descriptors using the `FD_ISSET` macro in a simple loop. This can be translated to the following sample :

```
for (i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; ++i) {
    if (FD_ISSET (i, &read_fd_set)) {
        if (i == bound_socket) {
            // A new client is waiting to be accepted
            new = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &clientname, &size);
            // ...
            FD_SET (new, &active_fd_set);
        }
        else {
          // There is something to be read on the file descriptor.
          data = read_from_client_on(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, this is just sample which is obviously lacking any error handling, which you should handle in your application.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, this is a simple explanation. I forgot that `select()` is implemented as a bit mask, so I didn't understand the use of `FD_SET` until I saw your explanation and loop.